# How to "Show information about an Eloquent model" that is not in App\Models namespace

Tags: laravel, eloquent, console, laravel-artisan

Most of the time i need to see what in which model, i do the following:

1. Open the model file and see relationships
2. Open the database and see what fields it have

But now I use the artisan command `php artisan model:show ModelName` which gives the almost same details about the model's both relationships and database fields, but the problem is that, some of my models are not in `App\Models` directly they reside in `App\`, `App\Models\Performance` and so on.

How to show details of a model that is either namespace.

I walked through the laravel blog to find any way but came back empty handed.

Comment: how about `php artisan model:show Performance\ModelName` ?

Comment: I can understand why some models are under `Models\Subfolder` but why are they out of the `Models` folder?

Comment: If models are inside models/subfolder, then do `php artisan model:show Subfolder\ModelName`, else you may need to extend the `model:show` command so that you can control where the source of the model is

Comment: We have more than 300 models, so based on the practical application of the project, we need to keep them out of models directory, but none of the above worked as it is looking for App\Models not any other.

Comment: But the thing i liked in your comments is to extend the command, will try it.

Comment: Try using the FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) of the model, for example, if you have model `Car` in `\App\Domain\Classes`, then try using `php artisan model:show \App\Domain\Classes\Car` and let us know if it worked

Comment: @matiaslauriti, not full qualified namespace but the namespace after models like App\Models\Performance\Vendor so using ```php artisan model:show \Performance/Vendor``` works but not working a model is not in models namespace